# Python - Dimension of Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python.

In R, you can get the dimension of a matrix using dim(...).   What is the corresponding function in Python Pandas for their data frame?

Comment: For a detailed summary of all the ways to get dimension info on DataFrames and Series [see this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47139464/3707607)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`df.shape`, where `df` is your DataFrame.

Answer (score 43):

## Summary of all ways to get info on dimensions of DataFrame or Series

There are a number of ways to get information on the attributes of your DataFrame or Series.

**Create Sample DataFrame and Series**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[5, 2, np.nan], 'b':[ 9, 2, 4]})
df

     a  b
0  5.0  9
1  2.0  2
2  NaN  4

s = df['a']
s

0    5.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

#### `shape` Attribute

The `shape` attribute returns a two-item tuple of the number of rows and the number of columns in the DataFrame. For a Series, it returns a one-item tuple.

```
df.shape
(3, 2)

s.shape
(3,)
```

---

#### `len` function

To get the number of rows of a DataFrame or get the length of a Series, use the `len` function. An integer will be returned.

```
len(df)
3

len(s)
3
```

---

#### `size` attribute

To get the total number of elements in the DataFrame or Series, use the `size` attribute. For DataFrames, this is the product of the number of rows and the number of columns. For a Series, this will be equivalent to the `len` function:

```
df.size
6

s.size
3
```

---

#### `ndim` attribute

The `ndim` attribute returns the number of dimensions of your DataFrame or Series. It will always be 2 for DataFrames and 1 for Series:

```
df.ndim
2

s.ndim
1
```

---

#### The tricky `count` method

The `count` method can be used to return the number of non-missing values for each column/row of the DataFrame. This can be very confusing, because most people normally think of count as just the length of each row, which it is not. When called on a DataFrame, a Series is returned with the column names in the index and the number of non-missing values as the values.

```
df.count() # by default, get the count of each column

a    2
b    3
dtype: int64


df.count(axis='columns') # change direction to get count of each row

0    2
1    2
2    1
dtype: int64
```

For a Series, there is only one axis for computation and so it just returns a scalar:

```
s.count()
2
```

---

### Use the `info` method for retrieving metadata

The `info` method returns the number of non-missing values and data types of each column

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    2 non-null float64
b    3 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 128.0 bytes
```